# Where did the word "buckle" come from?

Tags: etymology, nouns

*Buckle* is used mostly for the thing that's on belts. Where did the word come from?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. For answering simple etymology question, we like to consult [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=buckle&searchmode=term).

Comment: Interesting comment at etymonline about the boss of a shield. I wondered why armaments were called "sword and buckler".

Comment: @Andrew@ the OED entry includes "Sometimes wrongly applied to any kind of shield. Also attrib."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s from Latin *buccula*, the diminutive of *bucca* meaning cheek. That’s because a *buccula* was once the cheek-strap of a helmet.